# Check today is between start date and expired date using Carbon?

Tags: laravel-5

I have to check whether coupon is active, or no by checking that today is between start date and expired date.

My start date and expired date format is `01/12/2017`

Let assume, today is `21/06/2017`

Coupon start date is `19/06/2017` and expired date is `23/06/2017`

So it should result in `Coupon is Active`, wheter today is less than coupon start and expired date it should result in `Coupon is Expired`

So far I didn't find any tutorial which comparing today with start and expired date using Carbon.

Almost all tutorial like this

```
$now = Carbon::now();

$end_date = Carbon::parse($request->input('end_date'));

$lengthOfAd = $end_date->diffInDays($now);
```

So How I can check if today is between start date and expired date, and today is less than start date and expired date using Carbon in Laravel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a very simple task using `Carbon`, all you can do is call the `between` method of carbon :

```
$now = Carbon::now();

$start_date = Carbon::parse($request->input('start_date'));

$end_date = Carbon::parse($request->input('end_date'));

if($now->between($start_date,$end_date)){
    echo 'Coupon is Active';
} else {
    echo 'Coupon is Expired';
}
```

You can add a third parameter to the `between` method to use `or equal` like discribed in the [doc](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison)

> To determine if the current instance is between two other instances you can use the aptly named between() method. The third parameter indicates if an equal to comparison should be done. The default is true which determines if its between or equal to the boundaries.